# Transpose rows to columns in splunk search

Tags: search, splunk

I have a table from a search query which has 5 rows and 1 column (known as host_type). I want to transpose the table in such a way so that I get 5 columns and 1 row. Any help will be appreciated.

This is the query I am using:

```
host_type=* sourcetype=* index=* xyz | fields host_type
```

Comment: Have you tried the [transpose](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/Transpose) command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Splunk Transpose command may help:

```
transpose
Description
Returns the specified number of rows (search results) as columns (list of field values), such that each search row becomes a column.

Syntax
transpose [int] [column_name=<string>] [header_field=<field>] [include_empty=<bool>]
```

for more information on it check out:
    http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.2/SearchReference/Transpose